# Where does file store for [NSTableView setAutosaveName]?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

After manually creating `NSTableView` columns, I have called 
`[self.tableView setAutosaveName:@"MyTable"]` and `[self.tableView setAutosaveTableColumns:YES]`

Ok, it works.

After closing the App I have a file `~/Library/Preferences/MyApp.plist` and it has my table settings.

I delete this file and relaunch App and I have seen changed position and size of columns. Not default!

I have tried find where this settings were stored but nothing.

Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a server process, `cfprefsd`, that caches and serves the user defaults. Apps communicate with that. They don't directly access the file. It has never been reliable to directly manipulate the file as a means of changing the defaults.

To manipulate the user defaults, you must either use the `CFPreferences` or `NSUserDefaults` APIs programmatically or, from a command line, use the `defaults` program. For example:

```
defaults delete com.yourdomain.yourapp
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Last question - How long time this process keeps cache?

Comment: That's an implementation detail. Apple doesn't say and you can't rely on it. Also, when the server process exits, it's somewhat likely that it will write the cache out to file. So, in a sense, it doesn't matter when the process exits. The data persists either way.